# SOA service gets null ejb instance using spring

Tags: java, spring, soap, ejb, cxf

I have a maven project that implements apache cxf web service and a ejb object, I'm trying inject the ejb instance using spring, when I run the program, the spring container returns the ejb bean as a null. I don't understand how to relate the ejb implementation with the spring bean.

The project has a apache cxf implementation, this way:

ServiceBindingImpl

```
@WebService(endpointInterface = "cl.flying.binding.ServiceBinding")
public class ServiceBindingImpl implements ServiceBinding { 
    private ServiceBusinessLocal serviceEjb
    public void setServiceEjb(ServiceBusinessLocal serviceEjb) {
        this.serviceEjb = serviceEjb
    }
    public String sayHello(String request) {
        return serviceEjb.sayHello(request);
    }
}
```

It also has a spring configuration in order to achieve DI, applicationContext.xml

```
<bean id="serviceEjb"
    class="org.springframework.ejb.access.LocalStatelessSessionProxyFactoryBean" scope="request">
    <property name="jndiName" value="ejb/ServiceBusinessImpl" />
    <property name="businessInterface" value="cl.service.business.ServiceBusinessLocal" />
    <property name="resourceRef" value="true" />
</bean>
<bean id="ServiceController" class="cl.flying.binding.ServiceBindingImpl">
    <property name="serviceEjb" ref="serviceEjb" />
</bean>
```

That is the business tier, Stateless ejb implementation:

```
@Stateless(mappedName="ejb/ServiceBusiness")
public class ServiceBusinessImpl implements ServiceBusinessLocal
    public String sayHello(String request) {
        return "hello: " + request;
    }
}
```

How can I instantiate the ejb object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the bean configuration file I used as part POC sometime back

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-4.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-4.2.xsd">

    <jee:remote-slsb id="calculatorRemote" business-interface="com.kp.swasthik.remote.CalculatorRemote" jndi-name="java:kp-ejb/Calculator!com.kp.swasthik.remote.CalculatorRemote" lookup-home-on-startup="true" >
        <jee:environment>
             java.naming.factory.initial=org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory
             java.naming.provider.url=http-remoting://localhost:8080
             jboss.naming.client.ejb.context=true
             java.naming.security.principal=username
             java.naming.security.credentials=password
        </jee:environment>
    </jee:remote-slsb>

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.kp.swasthik.jaxws"></context:component-scan>

    <util:properties id="remoteRef">
        <prop key="java.naming.factory.initial">org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory</prop>
        <prop key="java.naming.provider.url">remote://localhost:4447</prop>
        <prop key="java.naming.factory.url.pkgs">org.jboss.ejb.client.naming</prop>
    </util:properties>

</beans>
```

And injecting the bean as shown below.

```
@Service
@WebService
public class KPService {

    @Autowired
    CalculatorRemote calc;

    @WebMethod
    public int add(int a, int b){
        return calc.add(a, b);
    }


    @WebMethod
    public Result subtract(Input num){
         return calc.subtract(num);
    }

}
```

**NOTE: The above configuration is for Wildfly/JBOSS EAP, you might need to change accordingly to your app server**